# ROS2 Gazebo vacuum_gripper doesn't grip

Tags: gazebo, ros2, gazebo-plugin, gripper

I am trying to add a vacuum gripper to my ROS2/Gazebo/Python project.
I have the following:

grip.xacro (note the plugin for gripper):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

...
<gazebo>
    <plugin name='vacuum_gripper' filename='libgazebo_ros_vacuum_gripper.so'>

      <ros>
        <!-- Add a namespace -->
        <!-- namespace>/demo</namespace -->

        <!-- Remap service name -->
        <remapping>switch:=custom_switch</remapping>

        <!-- Remap publisher topic name -->
        <remapping>grasping:=custom_grasping</remapping>
      </ros>

      <!-- Link associated with gripper -->
      <link_name>gripper_link_right_1</link_name>

      <!-- Max and min distance to attract entities -->
      <max_distance>10.0</max_distance>

      <!-- List of entities to be not attracted by the gripper -->
      <fixed>ground_plane</fixed>
      <!-- fixed>wall</fixed -->

    </plugin>
</gazebo>
    <!-- Gazebo colors -->

    <gazebo reference="gripper_link_base">
        <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
    </gazebo>
    <gazebo reference="gripper_link_left_1">
        <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
    </gazebo>     
    <gazebo reference="gripper_link_right_1">
        <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    </gazebo>           

</robot>
```

Then from the code I have to switch this thing on and off. I understand (correct me please if I am wrong) that it is done by calling service, so I have created a client:

self.init():

```
# Create a client for the vacuum gripper's switch service
self.vacuum_switch_client = self.create_client(SetBool, 'custom_switch')
while not self.vacuum_switch_client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
    print('Service not available, waiting...')
```

To turn it on/off, I use messages:

```
    self.vacuum_state = False

    # Create a service to turn the vacuum on or off
    self.vacuum_subscriber = self.create_subscription(
        Bool,
        'vacuum_control_topic',
        self.vacuum_control_callback,
        10
    )
```

To handle both message and a switch:

```
def vacuum_control_callback(self, msg):
    if msg.data:
        # Turn on the vacuum gripper
        request = SetBool.Request()
        request.data = True
        future = self.vacuum_switch_client.call_async(request)
        future.add_done_callback(self.vacuum_switch_callback)
    else:
        # Turn off the vacuum gripper
        request = SetBool.Request()
        request.data = False
        future = self.vacuum_switch_client.call_async(request)
        future.add_done_callback(self.vacuum_switch_callback)

def vacuum_switch_callback(self, future):
    try:
        response = future.result()
        if response.success:
            print('Vacuum gripper: switched successfully')
        else:
            print('Vacuum gripper: failed to switch')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Vacuum gripper: service call failed:', str(e))
```

As the result, when I send (from the command line):

```
$ ros2 topic pub /vacuum_control_topic std_msgs/msg/Bool "data: true"
```

all functions are properly called and I get
'Vacuum gripper: switched successfully'

The "link6" above does exist, and I assume that it should suck objects in. To check it, I have placed a cube in the world:

```
<model name="box_01">
  <pose>-0.54 0.01 0.0 0 0 0</pose>
  <link name="link">
    <collision name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <contact>
        <plugin name="box_01_contact_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_contact.so"/>
    </contact>
    <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
            <box>
            <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
            </box>
        </geometry>
        <material>
            <script>
                <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
                <name>Gazebo/Blue</name>
            </script>
        </material>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
        <mass value="0.25"/>
        <inertia ixx="1e-1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-1" iyz="0.0" izz="1e-1"/>
    </inertial>
    <surface>
        <friction>
            <ode>
                <mu>1.0</mu>
                <mu2>1.0</mu2>
            </ode>
        </friction>
        <contact>
            <ode>
                <kp>100</kp>
                <kd>100</kd>
                <min_depth>0.001</min_depth>
                <max_vel>0.0</max_vel>
            </ode>
        </contact>
    </surface>        
  </link>
</model>
```

However, when the "link6" is close to cube, and I send message to turn on the gripper, the cube doesn't "jump" to the link6, so I believe, sucktion doesn't work (regardless the message that it was turned on).

So, apparently, I do something wrong. Please help.

Comment: Are you using Gazebo Sim or Gazebo Classic?

Comment: Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.11.0

Comment: Can you please clarify the issue you're experiencing? I've tried to replicate the same process, but it doesn't seem to be functioning as expected.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/19747)

Comment: A workaround never asks a question :)
From what I found, you can not use distance-based controller in Gazebo to implement grabber, as it will vibrate and as the result, swith from "grab" to "release" and back. And object will slide off the grip.
So, the answer is: there is no solution. You need a workaround (like I did), you might write a plug-in, you might use existing plugin (like move-it), but using just Gazebo - nope.

Comment: To yehia mansour:
Could you please clarify: were you unable to replicate the problem or my solution to it?

Answer (score 1):

As you are on Gazebo Classic, I suggest to have a look at the Ariac [vacuum gripper plugin](https://github.com/usnistgov/ARIAC/blob/ariac2023/ariac_plugins/src/vacuum_gripper_plugin.cpp).

I haven't used it myself, and there is some ARIAC contest specific code in it (e.g. the [`OnTrialCallback()`](https://github.com/usnistgov/ARIAC/blob/66a0470be3d7f92201ff40ddeb5f74de14659ba1/ariac_plugins/src/vacuum_gripper_plugin.cpp#L180)), but as it is being used in the ARIAC contest, it should be functional.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 weeks of research :) I have created a workaround. A fully working gripper example [here](https://robotics.snowcron.com)

P.S. It is a long example, with couple of sub-workarounds, so I am not going to post it here.