# Basic example project of a gripper holding an object in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-control, ros-humble, gripper, grasping

I am searching for a working example of a gripper that can hold an object in Gazebo / Gazebo Classic. The example should ideally:

- use a 1-DOF gripper with two fingers where one is mimicked
- use Python for controlling
- use only minimal number of libraries

I tried:

- using `ros2_control`, however [the Humble version has problems with effort-based control and mimicked fingers](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/103967/which-controller-from-ros2-control-is-appropriate-for-firmly-grabbing-a-box-wi).
- following [Gazebo Tutorial: Make a Simple Gripper](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=simple_gripper&cat=build_robot), however I could not hold the object, it slips.

Slipping objects from the gripper in Gazebo seem to be a popular problem and I found some workarounds that basically attach the object/s to the gripper (vacuum or two fingers):

- [IFRA Link Attacher](https://github.com/IFRA-Cranfield/IFRA_LinkAttacher)
- [Gazebo Grasp Fix](https://github.com/JenniferBuehler/gazebo-pkgs/blob/master/gazebo_grasp_plugin/src/GazeboGraspFix.cpp) — [here is a ROS1 video tutorial that uses it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWr09TJvOO8)
- [Code from a competition named ARIAC](https://github.com/usnistgov/ARIAC/blob/66a0470be3d7f92201ff40ddeb5f74de14659ba1/ariac_plugins/src/vacuum_gripper_plugin.cpp#L198-L203)

There is also an [alternative approach that periodically sets the position of the object](https://robotics.snowcron.com/robotics_ros2/robotic_arm_fixing_gripper_intro.htm) to make the object seem fixed.

I don't want to overcomplicate the project using extra Gazebo workaround code.

Finally [Moveit2 contains a pick and place example](https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/tutorials/pick_and_place_with_moveit_task_constructor/pick_and_place_with_moveit_task_constructor.html), however this is based on C++.

Do you know a minimal basic example project of a gripper holding an object that meets my expectations?

Comment: [Here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/103655/ros2-gazebo-vacuum-gripper-doesnt-grip/103807#103807) is an example mentioned, as well as further references.

Comment: Added the solutions in your link @JRTG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the current state-of-the-art attaches the object to the gripper via Gazebo when the object is in proximity, so the ideal solution that I am looking for does not seem to exist. I will use the workarounds that I listed in my question.

I hope other solutions will be posted here in future. According to [Jennifer Buehler in the Gazebo grasp fix plugin wiki](https://github.com/JenniferBuehler/gazebo-pkgs/wiki/The-Gazebo-grasp-fix-plugin) solutions without workarounds may exist:

> ... It may be possible to get the robot to grasp the object still, by adjusting the material properties of object and gripper. ...

Comment: Yes, thanks. Please don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer. You can always change the accepted answer, should you feel that a better answer has been posted, in the future.